# Rails 3: How to implement a query cache in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, mongodb, query-cache

I did some research about MongoDB and recognised that it doesn't have any query cache.

> MongoDB does not implement a query cache: MongoDB serves all queries directly from the indexes and/or data files. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/)

Is there a way to implement a query cache in Rails for MongoDB? I just want the same behaviour as the MySQL query cache. The same database query should be more faster on the second time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a caching layer using memcached, but MongoDB will probably still have the data paged into memory from the last read/write operation already.  Using your MongoDB server memory for memcached will compete with it's memory mapped file model.  Less memory for MongoDB means more swapping to disk.

If you're running map reduce jobs (large enough to cause paging), it may be worth caching results, but tracking updates properly could be very tricky.

Comment: +1 for this answer, the question is confusing how mongoDB operates.  He should read: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joshua! @Adam: I did read this short documentation of caching. Maybe I did not understand it correctly!? Does the OS store the results of MongoDB automatically in the memory? If yes, how can I retrieve this data again?

Comment: MongoDB uses memory mapped files, and then lets the OS manage the actual paging of data in/out of RAM.  Unless you have memory pressure elsewhere and data is paged out as a result, the data will still be in RAM when you access it, so the disk access is only needed the firs time.  Once you have warmed it up in this way, you can effectively think of MongoDB as an in-memory cache unless, of course, you run out of memory.